# how to change UITabBarItem's Title dynamically

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a *TabBarController* in my App, and the 2nd item should have title `Login` or `Profile` depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

in *TabBarController*:

```
import UIKit

class TabNavigationBarVC: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.delegate = self
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") {
            tabBar.items?[1].title = "Prof"
            tabBar.items?[1].image = UIImage(named: "user_male")

        } else {
            tabBar.items?[1].title = "Log"
            tabBar.items?[1].image = UIImage(named: "user_male")          
        }        
    }
}
```

and 2nd *TabBarItem* is connected with *RouterVC*:

```
import UIKit
class RouterViewController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let profile = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ComponentUserProfile") as? UserProfileViewController
        let login = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ComponentLogin")  as? LoginViewController
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") {
        //profile?.tabBarItem.title = "prr" - no effect
        //profile?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "PROFILE", image: UIImage(named: "user_male"), tag: 0) - no effect
            viewControllers = [profile] as! [UIViewController]
       } else {
        //login?.tabBarItem.title = "logg"- no effect
        //login?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "LOGIN", image: UIImage(named: "user_male"), tag: 0)- no effect
            viewControllers = [login] as! [UIViewController]
       }
    }
}
```

all works correctly but only when the user launches the app. Later, after the user has logged out, I would like the 2nd title in the tabBar to change from `Profile` to `login`, or  - when the user is successfully logged in - from `Login` to `Profile`. I tried something like commented lines of code in `RouterVC`, but nothing changed.

And in *LoginVC* this lines not working too:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarItem.title = "loggggg"
    }
```

How can I make this change dynamically?

Maybe I should write extension for `TabBarController` to track if `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")` is changed and display correct title of the `tabbarItem`?..

p.s.navigation between views, login/logout works good, the point is only in title

p.p.s - find the answer how get access to the title from view - add `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].title = "profile"`, but still looking for some common decision, like tracking `UserDefaults` key..

Answer (score 0):

you can update the selected Item title using

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem?.title = "demo"
```